# Use of LaTeX Syntax in R Presentation (`.Rpres`) Slide Title

Tags: r

I had a question about the us of LaTeX syntax in a Slide Title in R Presentation. The use of LaTeX as you would for a R markdown file works fine for the text in the actual body of the slide, but not the title. Example:

```
    $PM_{2.5}$ Concentrations
    =================================

    Graph of $PM_{2.5}$ concentrations
```

In this example, when the presentation file is run, the title will show exactly as is, whereas the information in the body of the slide will show as you would expect it to be shown as a LaTeX equation.

I have tried other general markdown functions in this title portion of each slide with similar results (i.e. `~~strikethrough~~`).

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't use this format, but I just tried with [ioslides](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#mathjax-equations) and it works fine

Comment: I don't think this is possible (with a straightforward solution). Even simple markdown is ignored in .Rpres titles, just try using `**` or `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Just found that the use of the alternative delimiters `\(...\)` works for this.

This should give you the desired result:

```
\(PM_{2.5}\) Concentrations
=================================

Graph of $PM_{2.5}$ concentrations
```